# Woocomerce add to cart Cannot read property '0' of null

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

i'm a newbie and i built a wordpress + woocomerce website.
I changed a lot of things on my php files and i just saw that i've got an error in a part of my site.
On the single product page, when i click on "add to cart", it's loading but never ending

I've got this error :

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of null
at ae (functions.js?ver=4.9.8:1)
at HTMLIFrameElement.<anonymous> (functions.js?ver=4.9.8:1)
at HTMLIFrameElement.dispatch (jquery.js?ver=1.12.4:3)
at HTMLIFrameElement.r.handle (jquery.js?ver=1.12.4:3)
```

I don't really know what to do or where to look :(

the strangest thing is that if i'm refreshing the page, the product is on my cart !

Is anyone can help me, thank you very much !

Comment: Please provide the code that is causing the error, can't really do much with just the error

Comment: As @APAD1 we need the concerned JS code to help. Your browser debugger should be able to let you where the error is thrown.

Comment: I'm sorry it's the first time i'm psting. On the debuger tje code is like 90000 characters ... How can i find the part of the error ? @Mtxz